# REST command comes over as RE*T when trying to do a ftp transfer

Tags: filezilla, ftp

I am trying to resume a file transfer of a set of large files. Both sides are using Filezilla.

On the client side the log says

```
Command:    TYPE I
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,215)
Command:    REST 483330080
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,216)
Command:    REST 504011792
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.001
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.002
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,217)
Command:    REST 483330080
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,218)
Command:    REST 504011792
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.001
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.002
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,219)
Command:    REST 483330080
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,220)
Command:    REST 504011792
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.003
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.004
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,221)
Command:    REST 60429777
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,222)
Command:    REST 65549620
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.003
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.004
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,223)
Command:    REST 60429777
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,224)
Command:    REST 65549620
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.003
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.004
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,225)
Command:    REST 60429777
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,226)
Command:    REST 65549620
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.005
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Status: Starting upload of D:\7-ZipPortable\716 Image.7z.006
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,227)
Command:    REST 0
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,228)
Command:    REST 0
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Command:    STOR 716 Image.7z.005
Response:   500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
Command:    STOR 716 Image.7z.006
Response:   150 Connection accepted
Response:   150 Connection accepted
```

On the server the log says

```
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> TYPE I
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 200 Type set to I
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> TYPE I
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 200 Type set to I
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,215)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,216)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 483330080
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 504011792
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,217)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:38 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,218)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 483330080
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 504011792
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,219)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,220)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 483330080
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 504011792
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,221)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,222)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 60429777
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 65549620
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,223)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,224)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 60429777
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 65549620
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,225)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,226)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 60429777
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 65549620
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,227)
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> PASV
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (74,62,95,113,243,228)
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 0
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> RE*T 0
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> STOR 716 Image.7z.005
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> STOR 716 Image.7z.006
(000074)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 150 Connection accepted
(000075)6/17/2011 9:24:39 AM - srchamberlain (75.151.243.41)> 150 Connection accepted
```

Notice that REST became RE*T. If it was some strange encoding issue why does the S in STOR or in PASV work? Has anyone seen this issue before and know how to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *very* likely to be a firewall mucking with FTP commands it doesn't support. (Many consumer firewalls scan FTP traffic for PORT and PASV commands and adjust rules accordingly.)

Temporarily disable your firewall, or use secure FTP with TLS (SSL).

Comment: Setting up a self signed cert on the ftp server fixed the issue, thank you!